# Stuck on responsible flex boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, formatting

got a problem with wrapping a flexbox, when the width is too small to display both. Here is a fullscreen screen: [Shows a fullscreen-site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6B98.png)

So here is what happens if reduce the browser width: [reduced width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeUt1.png)

Now, if I reduce the width again, it looks like that: [1 mm more reduced than before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yApBr.png)

But of course, it should be among themselves.

```css
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#Wrapper,
body,
html,
main,
nav,
header,
div,
class,
footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {}

header h1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  top: 8vh;
  left: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
  color: deeppink;
}

.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 16em;
  background-color: lightslategrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="Wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <h1>This is a heading and it's extra long to test stuff.</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="Container">
      <div class="item">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: The height of your flexbox is restricted and the height of the items not defined (the default setting is "stretch"). Change either and both items will become visible on a smaller screen.

Comment: That was it! Thanks very much :D

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues on your CSS that forces this behavior on your boxes **item**.
The main issue is that you limit your container to a width of 40% and then when you resize your window, there's no space for the inner boxes to be displayed correctly.
I'd give a full *width: 100%* to the container, *left: 0* and *justify-content: center*.
Then I'd give *margins-left* and *right* to the inner items.

So your CSS to something like this:

```
.Container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item {
    width: 16em;
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    margin: 0 30px;
}
```

This solves partially the issue as your inner boxes are still overlaped if you reduce your window size.
To solve it for real, you'd probably need a [mediaquery](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to make the inner boxes smaller when the window is resized.

It could be something like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
  .item {
        width: 8em;
  }
}
```

Here's a codepen so you can see the results: https://codepen.io/annabranco/pen/VEjXOL

Comment: Hey, very cool! But the codepen for whatever reason, looks different from mine, if I paste your updates CSS.  The boxes (items) are directly to each other like you see here: https://gyazo.com/66cbdef0093b90845625a034a723168d

This problem's doesn't exist on your codepen for some reason. I copied your CSS from the codepen and from right here, both results are same, they are close to each other. I used Space-around fix that, but I couldn't use "center" if I use "justify-content: center".